# Fixed footer gets out of place when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed footer of 970px width, but when I resize my browser smaller the whole footer keeps going off screen with the center of the footer in the middle. I want my footer to stop going off screen when resizing the browser smaller than 970px width.

**CSS**

```
footer{
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    width: 940px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(#232323, #1f1f1f);
    margin: 0 auto 0 -485px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<footer>Footer Text</footer>
```

Anybody know how I could achieve that?

Comment: your footer has a fixed width, if you resize your screen to smaller than the width, the footer will be off screen or get cut off by the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say without any HTML, but from what I can guess you have two options:

1. You want to stop the footer being bigger than the browser if the browser is < 940px, if that is so why not set it to have `width:100%` and `max-width:940px;`. You may also want `overflow:hidden;`,
2. Your footer isnt centering properly, in that case wrap it within a div with `width:100%` (or calculated to be as wide as your page) with `text-align:center;` and give the footer (placed within the div) `margin:0 auto;`

Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHUTN/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a negative left margin of `-485px` and a left position of `50%`. I would just use

```
footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and remove the left position altogether.

Comment: yea usually centering horizontally is easier. The OP attempts to center using the vertical centering trick. I am not sure what OP means by off screen since he has a fixed width footer when resizing the footer will go off screen no matter what

Comment: IIRC, the very first version had no `text-align: center`. Without center, the text would vanish to the left side, when the window shrinks smaller than the footer width. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv2eN/) as example.

Comment: When I do it this way it does actually do what I want, however it is not centered but aligned to the left.